# ValueError: zero-dimensional arrays cannot be concatenated when arrays are not zero-dimensional and inside bracket/parenthesis

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

```
        print(foo.shape)  # prints(1,6,288,512)

        for i in range(2):
            print(foo[:,i].shape,foo[:,i+2].shape, foo[:,i+4].shape)
            # prints (1, 288, 512) for all three

            fi = np.concatenate([foo[:,i],foo[:,i+2], foo[:,i+4]],axis=0)
            #expecting fi to be a (3,288,512) array
```

the last line returns

```
ValueError: zero-dimensional arrays cannot be concatenated
```

Arrays are not zero-dimensional, and I've put bracket/parenthesis around the arrays I want to concatenate, so I'm not sure how it is even possible. Numpy version is 1.18.2, with python 3.6.

----------------added-----------
When I stack it instead, it doesn't return an error, but the shape of resulting array is strange.

```
fi = np.stack([foo[:,i],foo[:,i+2], foo[:,i+4]],axis=0)
print(fi.shape)
# returns (3,)
```

Comment: If you found the error - state so, and delete the question.  We don't need to waste time it.

Answer (score 0):

The arrays should be fed to [`np.concatenate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html) as a tuple:

```
np.concatenate((foo[:,i],foo[:,i+2], foo[:,i+4]),axis=0)
```

should work.

---

More concretely the following MWE works for me:

```
foo = np.ones((1, 6, 288, 512))

bar = np.concatenate((foo[:, 0], foo[:, 2], foo[:, 4]), axis=0)  # no exception raised
print(bar.shape) # prints (3, 288, 512)
```

Comment: That's strange.   See my update --- for me it works!

Comment: it is quite strange.. I've added additional info just in case

Comment: Have you tried replacing the actual contents of `foo` with something like all `ones`?

Comment: replacing it with ones worked. Does it mean that the data inside the array is the problem?

Comment: I've found out the problem! foo was a tensor NdArray variable, so I had to access its data with foo.data

Comment: It doesn't matter whether the arrays are in a list or tuple.